# Application to control GoPro camera from Windows Vista

Tags: windows, gopro

I need to control a GoPro Hero 3+ Black from my Windows Vista. I tried WiGo by CamDo but it keeps losing connection to the camera.

Are there alternatives to controlling a GoPro from a PC?

Comment: Your question is lacking details.  Please see [How Do I ask a Good Question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As already pointed out, and here some additional hints: what do you want to control, what tasks to perform? What are you willing to invest (price of the product/license/subscription)? The better you describe your needs, the better answers can fit them :)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack

This is the best solution I've found. The GoPro acts as a server. Thus, you can use `curl` from the command line to call different URLs to make the camera do different things.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [BlueStacks](https://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/BlueStacks_App_Player) which is a easy-to-use Android simulator for Windows.
Install the GoPro app from Google Play on the system a computer with Wi-Fi, and see if you can connect.
Android 4.4.4 seems like the latest official version, download [here](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=457095661767110778).
I've used it myself for other purposes.